# Faster way of fillna() with a group by clause

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to perform a fillna() but following a group by clause. I found this one-liner

```
df["val"] = df.groupby(["group_by1", "group_by2"]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

We could just write a couple for loops (I know not Pythonic!)

```
l = []
for f, df_f in df.groupby('group_by1'):
    for h, df_h in df_f.groupby('group_by2'):
        df_copy = df_h.copy()
        df_copy['val'].fillna(df_copy['val'].median(),inplace=True)
        l.append(df_copy)
```

then just concat

```
df_output = pd.concat(l)
```

I noticed the for loops are a lot faster. Although when I was testing this, the for loop approach still contained some NaN values which I thought was odd (or most likely did something wrong). Thus, my question is simple, what method should I use? Is there something faster?

Here is an example dataframe to use

```
N = 20_000 ; df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.choice([1, np.nan], p=[0.9, 0.1], size=N), 'group_by1': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=N), 'group_by2': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=N),})
```

Comment: Can you provide code to set up a fully reproducible example? What is the size of you teat DataFrame? `groupby` is using a python loop so it should have a similar speed, but if you're measuring on a tiny DataFrame you might just time the overhead.

Comment: @mozway The shape of the dataframe is (966382, 405), should I create an example here on the question? I thought that would take too much space...

Comment: Not if you provide **code** to build a test DataFrame, I'm testing it now it takes 3 lines of code ;)

Comment: @mozway Want to share so I can make the question better :)

Comment: Something like: `N = 20_000 ; df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.choice([1, np.nan], p=[0.9, 0.1], size=N), 'group_by1': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=N), 'group_by2': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=N),})`, so far I reproduced your claims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think faster is avoid lambda function and replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and `mean`:

```
#thank you mozway
np.random.seed(203)
N = 20_000  
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.choice([1, np.nan], p=[0.9, 0.1], size=N), 
                   'group_by1': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=N),
                   'group_by2': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=N)})


In [8]: %timeit df.groupby(["group_by1", "group_by2"])['val'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
26 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit df["val"].fillna(df.groupby(["group_by1","group_by2"])['val'].transform('mean'))
2.76 ms ± 279 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Tested your second solution:

```
In [10]: %%timeit
    ...: l = []
    ...: for f, df_f in df.groupby('group_by1'):
    ...:     for h, df_h in df_f.groupby('group_by2'):
    ...:         df_copy = df_h.copy()
    ...:         df_copy['val'].fillna(df_copy['val'].mean(),inplace=True)
    ...:         l.append(df_copy)
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: df_output = pd.concat(l)
    ...: 
49.8 ms ± 4.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```